# Error " Value of type 'String' has no member 'URLbyAppending' " with my Record Function

Tags: swift, audio, record

I'm getting an error with my record audio function ... 
it says " Value of type 'String' has no member 'URLbyAppending' "

```
    func startRecording() {
        let audioFilename = getDocumentsDirectory().URLbyAppending("recording.m4a")
        let audioURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioFilename)

        let settings = [
            AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
            AVSampleRateKey: 12000.0,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1 as NSNumber,
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.High.rawValue
        ]
```

It's very annoying because before with my Xcode 6 it was working perfectly...

I need some help please... Thank you

EDIT

Here is my getDocumentsDirectory Function

```
    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> String {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
```

Comment: What does getDocumentsDirectory() return, a string or a URL? Perhaps you mean stringByAppendingPathComponent. Also, by convention methods are not prefixed by get unless they return values via a reference parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getDocumentsDirectory` function, which you should have included, apparently returns a string, not a URL.  Fix it by using `stringByAppendingPathComponent`.

Alternatively, you can change your `getDocumentsDirectory` function to return a url directly and changing your calling to:

```
func getDocumentsDirectory() throws -> NSURL {
    return try NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)
}

let audioUrl = try getDocumentsDirectory().URLByAppendingPathComponent("recording.m4a")
```

Note that since getDocumentsDirectory can throw (URLForDirectory can throw) getDocumentsDirectory must be called with try.

Comment: Probably not: `stringByAppendingPathElement`, there is no such method. Perhaps: `stringByAppendingPathComponent`.

Comment: Yeah, was double checking that and fixed it before I saw your comment ;). What I get for answering from the iPad.

Comment: How do i make return to an URL? by changing my getDocumentsDirectory func?

Comment: If you did that, then you wouldn't need the NSURL constructor below and your variables would be misnamed :)